# Where is the publishing page in the SharePoint Online trial

Tags: sharepoint-online

I was reading a post from [here](http://en.share-gate.com/blog/sharepoint-wiki-publishing-web-part-pages-overview). And It said there exist a page type named `Publishing Page` in the `SharePoint 2013`. But I wonder if there exist this kind of page in the `SharePoint 2013 Online`. And In my experience, It seems there is only the `Wiki Page` can be created in the `SharePoint 2013 Online trial`. Thanks.

**Updated**

Let's say the default `Site` of `Site Collection` in my `SharePoint Online` trial.
It is `Https://beyondhard.sharepoint.com`.

You can see the feature is enabled .

[image]

But in the `Site Pages` app. When I tried to create a new page by clicking `new` button. didn't found any type selecting in there. Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried enabling the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature in Site Settings > Site Collection features?

Comment: yes, I am sure I enable the `SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure feature`, But I didn't found any type- selecting when I create a new page item . Did I missing something? thanks.

Comment: And if you follow z.rahui's answer and enable the web feature as well... does it work then? Another option is to create a Publishing Site Collection (as a template) and it will be on by default. I hade the E3 subscription plan on trial for a month and had all features of a regular subscription available...

Comment: Yeah, I already enabled the `SharePoint Server Publishing` in the Site level following the `z.rahui` answser(+1)(Doesn't work). Now I am trying to create one site collection from a Publishing Site Template .

Comment: Yeah, Right , Only in the `Publishing Site` The `Publish` button can be found in the edit page. So Is it the reason for the issue? And it seems only the Publishing page can be created in there ... thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from enabling the Site Collection Feature *SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure* and the Site Feature *SharePoint Server Publishing* you need to enable versioning on the SitePages Library Setting. When this is done (it may take a few minutes to provision) - you are in a state where you can publish/unpublish pages.

[image]

You find the Document Version History in

- *Site Contents* > *Site Pages* > *Library Tab (in the ribbon)* > *Library Settings* > *Versioning Settings*

Answer (score 1):

Publishing Pages require the Publishing feature to be enabled on both the Site Collection and Web level.

You can enable these by going to Site Settings on your root website and first enabling `SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure` under your Site Collection features.

Then enable on the Web by going to Site Features and enabling `SharePoint Server Publishing`

For more information, visit [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/sharepoint-server-help/enable-publishing-features-HA102802294.aspx)

Comment: Please see my comment above. Thanks. It seems the two feature enabled doesn't work for non-publishing site.  Thanks.